# Узор поверх всех изображений на сайте

Tags: css, css3

Появилась необходимость добавить некоторый узор поверх всех изображений на сайте. Сделать нужно в браузере, а не на сервере, но так как тег `img` не поддерживает наличия псевдоэлементов, делаю при помощи `div`-обертки, добавляемой каждому изображению при помощи `JavaScript`. Есть ли какая-нибудь хитрость для подобных целей или только так решается проблема?

Comment: А зачем обертка, если можно прямо с помощью JS вешать узор, а не обертку?

Comment: к `body` можно подключить `background` с немалым `z-index`.

Comment: Теоретически, нормальное решение, не видел, чтобы подобное решалось как-то проще